# Meteor: Exception in Template Helper not going away

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm getting the following error from the sidebar in my app.

> Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'org' of undefined
>       at Object.Template.sidebar.helpers.orgUsers (http://localhost:3000/client/templates/includes/sidebar.js?85f4645305c91378ab2c0648488f2250753e8c70:3:29)
>       at bindDataContext (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?4e49999979a58da0e2265f7bd3f5910f9901b07b:2786:16)
>       at Blaze._wrapCatchingExceptions (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?4e49999979a58da0e2265f7bd3f5910f9901b07b:1607:16)
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?4e49999979a58da0e2265f7bd3f5910f9901b07b:2834:66
>       at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?4e49999979a58da0e2265f7bd3f5910f9901b07b:3382:12)
>       at wrapHelper (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?4e49999979a58da0e2265f7bd3f5910f9901b07b:2833:27)
>       at Object.Spacebars.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?7bafbe05ec09b6bbb6a3b276537e4995ab298a2f:172:18)
>       at http://localhost:3000/client/templates/includes/template.sidebar.js?85456dfc1ce0f189b2d312b2422db8a2e35f337e:15:22
>       at null. (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?4e49999979a58da0e2265f7bd3f5910f9901b07b:2583:27)
>       at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?4e49999979a58da0e2265f7bd3f5910f9901b07b:1821:18

The sidebar should display a list of users specific to the org(anization). The helper sending users is as follows:

```
Template.sidebar.helpers({
  orgUsers : function() {
    var org_id = Meteor.user().org._id;

    var users = Meteor.users.find({
        "org._id" : org_id
    });
    return users;
  }
});
```

I publish the user.org here:

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function() {
    if (this.userId) {
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
            {fields: {'org._id': 1, 'org.active' : 1, 'emails.[0].address': 1, 'profile.name': 1, 'createdAt':1}});
    } else {
        this.ready();
    }   
});
```

Currently I'm publishing this to every page with Iron Router. It appears the helper is run several times, and the first couple times it doesn't have the org_id nor org._id, but it eventually get it and displays. I'm getting this nasty console error every page refresh though. Any help is much appreciated.

---

Router:

```
Router.configure({
layoutTemplate : 'layout',
loadingTemplate : 'loading',
notFoundTemplate : 'notFound',
waitOn : function() {
    return [ 
        Meteor.subscribe('orgUsers'),
        Meteor.subscribe('appointments'), 
        Meteor.subscribe('allServicesData'), 
        Meteor.subscribe('allOrgsData'), 
        Meteor.subscribe('userData'), 

    ];
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Your helper is running before the user object is available. You can either have iron-router *waitOn* your subscription (recommended approach) to *userData* or you can code your helper defensively:

```
Template.sidebar.helpers({
  orgUsers : function() {
    if ( Meteor.user() ){
      var org_id = Meteor.user().org._id;

      var users = Meteor.users.find({
        "org._id" : org_id
      });
      return users;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So the subscription is already waitedOn. I'm going to edit the question to show the router. I also tried the defensive helper code and it is still occuring.

Comment: You're doing `Meteor.user().org._id` and getting `Cannot read property 'org' of undefined` which means `Meteor.user()` doesn't exist at the point the code is running. If you've just checked it, it should!